# how to use Kendo chart library in Server side

Tags: c#, charts, highcharts, kendo-ui, server

I've a JSON object which contains data to be displayed as a chart. The charting library used is 'Kendo' chart. I wanted to generate a Kendo chart using the JSON data and then convert it into an image and tweet them using Tweetinvi. Could you please help how can I generate a Kendo chart on the server side and then convert it into an image? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party tool [inkscape.org](http://inkscape.org).

Below link is ASP.NET MVC example to save image using kendoui chart and linkscape.org:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/chart-inkscape-export

I hope help you.

Comment: Inkscape is used to convert a chart to pdf or image. But I'd like to know how to generate the Kendo chart from json object in server side c#?

Comment: Kendo chart can't generate chart in server side.why you want back json data to server and generate chart again? it's clear it's not good idea.you can save image and then send it.

Comment: On the server side, the chart needs to be converted to an image and then used an attachment to generate the tweet on a twitter account. The client is the twitter.com here.

json data -> chart -> image -> to Twitter